# Send Email from different email accounts

Tags: vba, outlook, excel-2013

When I send emails they go out from my personal inbox at work, but I need them to go out from another mailbox that I have access to. I have both mailboxes in my outlook.

Can I send emails from a specific mailbox?

Here is the code I am using. It does not find the 2nd item in my account.

```
 Sub Mail_small_Text_Change_Account()

    Dim cel As Range
    Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 1" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
          "This is line 4"

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each cel In Range(("C2"), Range("C2").End(xlDown))
        With OutMail
            .To = cel.Value
            '.CC = cel.Offset(0, 3).Value
            .Subject = "Benefits Refund"
            .Body = strbody
            .SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(2)
            .Send   'or use .Display
        End With

    Next

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Using a POP mail box, you can specify the user name and password for any account.

```
.To = "E@E.com"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "This is the Subject line"
.Body = "This is the body"
.SendUsingAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(1)
```

Comment: change Item(1) to the account.

Comment: AND - You need to have the account you want to use in outlook.

Comment: Here is a page that has a lot more info:  http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/account.htm